# What abbreviation should be used to refer to this site? SFSE

Tags: discussion

I've seen the abbreviation "SF" used in a couple different questions recently, both here as well as on Meta Stack Overflow (the network meta).

At first, I though the poster was asking about Server Fault, which is generally abbreviated as "SF".

There is the potential for a lot of confusion if this catches on?

Therefore, what is a more appropriate and less confusing abbreviation to use for Salesforce Stack Exchange so that it doesn't get confused with Server Fault when discussing this site elsewhere?

Comment: I agree with avoiding just "SF". For me it means "SourceForge", "San Francisco" or "Science Fiction".  Having a unique abbreviation to differentiate between Salesforce the company and the Stack Exchange community is a good idea.  How have other product-focused Stack Exchange sites handle naming?

Comment: SFSE is a great suggestion

Answer (score 11):

I agree: How about: SFSE - Salesforce Stack Exchange

Comment: I like the other suggestion of SFX, but this one edges ahead for me - points for obviousness.

Comment: I like SFSE because when I see SF elsewhere my mind expands it to Salesforce automatically when reading it. Likewise, when I see SFSE my mind expands it to Salesforce StackExchange. We should use the abbreviation in the faq.

Comment: What about EXSF or SFSEX? ;) I believe many products of salesforce are named with four letters, always starting with SF. Maybe we need some distinction in any direction. Maybe salesforce even launches a new product which will use these four letters (SalesForce Solution Exchange) or whatever. When i first read SFSE i thought it was another product of salesforce. Furthermore i thought of Salesforce Software Engineer, maybe  SFEX?

Answer (score 2):

SFX - SalesForce eXchange

I think whatever the final answer it will be a challenge to get everyone on board as I'm guessing a lot of people are use to using 'SF' to refer to anything Salesforce related

Comment: I use SF as shorthand for Salesforce, itself, a lot which a lot of people that I work with do.  I would never use it to refer to this site, though.  I generally don't refer to this site much in answers, so on the rare occasion that I would, I would probably just call it 'this site' or Salesforce StackExchange, etc.

Comment: SFX is quick to type, and while challenging, it's better to set the stage early on rather than later. Hopefully this helps! :)

Comment: @Peter Knolle - After using this site for a while I take back my comment completely.  Definitely need a good abbreviation.

Answer (score 0):

How about SFDC SE  or simply SFDC (Salesforce Developer Community)? This abbreviation emphasizes that this stack exchange is focussed on Salesforce development (code, point and click etc).

Anup

Comment: To me SFDC refers to the actual salesforce developer forums, but good suggestion none the less :)

Comment: For any Salesforce employee, SFDC = salesforce.com, the company